# Undefined variable in search function laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Okay somehow after I managed to fix the search function, it adds a completely new problem. Somehow my variable is undefined. This was not happened before adding the search function. The error is

> Undefined variable: pegawais (View: C:\Tugas\adminLTE\resources\views\pegawai\index.blade.php)

pegawaicontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Pegawai;


class pegawaicontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pegawais = Pegawai::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
        return view('pegawai.index', compact('pegawais')); 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pegawai.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'kategori' => 'required',
            'jabatan' => 'required',
            'nama_pegawai' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'gambar_pegawai' => 'required'
        ]);
            
        // upload file
        $filename = time() . '.png';
        $request->file('gambar_pegawai')->storeAs('public/images', $filename);

        $pegawai = new Pegawai;
        $pegawai->kategori = $request->input('kategori');
        $pegawai->jabatan = $request->input('jabatan');
        $pegawai->nama_pegawai = $request->input('nama_pegawai');
        $pegawai->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
        $pegawai->gambar_pegawai = $filename;
        $pegawai->save();
        // $pegawai = Pegawai::create($request->all()); 
        return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with('message','Data berhasil dibuat!'); 
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id);
        return view('pegawai.show', compact('pegawai'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id);
        return view('pegawai.edit', compact('pegawai')); 
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'kategori' => 'required',
            'jabatan' => 'required',
            'nama_pegawai' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'gambar_pegawai' => 'required'
        ]);
            
        // script delete tapii gagal
        // if ($request->produk()->gambar_pegawai){
        // Storage::delete('images/' . $request->produk()->gambar_pegawai);
        // }

        // update file
        $filename = time() . '.png';
        $request->file('gambar_pegawai')->storeAs('public/images', $filename);

        $pegawai = Pegawai::find($id);
        $pegawai->kategori = $request->input('kategori');
        $pegawai->jabatan = $request->input('jabatan');
        $pegawai->nama_pegawai = $request->input('nama_pegawai');
        $pegawai->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
        $pegawai->gambar_pegawai = $filename;
        $pegawai->save();

        // $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!'); 
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with('message', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->input('search');
        $pegawai = Pegawai::where('nama_pegawai', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('alamat', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
        return view('pegawai.index')->with('pegawai', $pegawai)->with('query', $q);
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/pegawai')->name('pegawai.index')->uses('pegawaicontroller@index');
Route::get('/search','pegawaicontroller@search');
```

pegawai.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pegawai extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['kategori', 'jabatan', 'nama_pegawai', 'alamat', 'gambar_pegawai', ];
}
```

index.php

```
@extends('template.adminlte')

@section('content')
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Menu Pegawai</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">pegawai</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>


    <form action="search" method="GET" role="Search" class="form-inline ml-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name=q>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>


 <section class="content">
 <div class="container-fluid">

 
 <a href="{{ route('pegawai.create') }}" class="btn btn-info btnsm float-right">
 <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Tambah Pegawai</i>
 </a><br><br>



 @if ($message = Session::get('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success martop-sm">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    </div>
 @endif
    <table class="table martop-sm">
    <thead> 
        <th>No</th>
        <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
        <th>Kategori</th>
        <th>Jabatan Pegawai</th>
        <th>Nama pegawai</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Foto Pegawai</th>
        <th>Aksi</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 @foreach ($pegawais as $key => $pegawai)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $pegawais->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
        <!-- <td>{{ $pegawai->id }}</td> -->
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->kategori }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->jabatan }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->nama_pegawai }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->alamat }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}"><img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $pegawai->gambar_pegawai) }}" alt="" width="100"></a></td>
        <td>
        <form action="{{ route('pegawai.destroy', $pegawai->id) }}" method="post"> 
        {{csrf_field()}} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <a href="{{ route('pegawai.edit', $pegawai->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Ubah</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapusnya?');">Hapus</button>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $pegawais -> links() }}
    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Its a typo! In your controller's `search` function, you're returning `with('pegawai', ...)`. It should be `with('pegawais', ...)` instead ('s' is missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though the problem was caused by a typo, there's some catch here. so i am adding an answer for you. you are returning to same view from both index and search function. in index the declared variable is `pegawais` and you are using pagination. the blade view handles that well. but from search function your declared variable is `pegawai`. so when returning to the view, you are getting this error that the variable is not defined. and simply you can rename the variable to `pegawais` and that error will be resolved. but in index function you used pagination and used that in blade too. in search you are not paginating and used `get()`. so you will get an error like `links()` does not exist. you have to use pagination here as well.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('search');
    $pegawais = Pegawai::where('nama_pegawai', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
    ->orWhere('alamat', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
    ->paginate(5);

    return view('pegawai.index')->with('pegawais', $pegawais)->with('query', $q);
}
```

and i believe the search you are using is the one at the index blade. in that form your input name is `q` but in controller you are looking for `search`. you will always get null. change the input name.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search">
```

Comment: Thank you sir i truly thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 return view('pegawai.index')->with('pegawais', $pegawais);
```